# no template defined wordpress masterstudy

Tags: wordpress, templates, tinymce

I'm trying to do the layout of a course on masterstudy in wordpress, but I'd like to make a template for certain parts of the course, lets say for example when I hover over the title, show an image, when I click on a paragraph, make another one appear next to it etc... I think it is possible to have shortcuts for these and not have to copy paste the code each time I want to have these effects. I think this icon(see image) might do the trick (not sure) but I can't seem to save a template in my dashboard. So if it is indeed this button, can you please explain me how to save templates, and if it is not the solution can you explain me where to look ? The screenshot shows the Tiny MCE editor

Thanks [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMM81.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please edit your question and add more information? Do you want this interactive parts to work with css or with js? you will need one of those at least. You should not / cannot paste in code to tiny mce, it is meant for dealing with content and access predefined styles. Are you looking for a way to extend the editor, or do you just want make the hover effects possible? Do you want to create your own theme for wordpress?

Comment: Hello, I'm sorry the question was not clear enough. What I want to do is lets say make a paragraph with a certain style or effect, with JS or CSS, and save the style that I applied on this pargraph somewhere so I can reuse it easily, without writing the css and js manually everytime. Do you see what I mean ? I assumed it was with the "template" button in tiny MCE that you retrieved those styles, but I'm not certain of this.

Comment: Well yes, but you can just use Css classes, define the style in your css, and apply the classes to the elements you want to them to use this style. This is the basic concept of css classes, so you do not to have duplicate code. If you want to build a template for the Tiny MCE, this is much more complex: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/template/#makingtemplates  Why do you use the tiny mce and not the Gutenberg Editor, is this part of your theme you are using?

Comment: I see, thanks ! Yes, tinyMCE is part of the template (master study). Cheers mate !

Comment: The template is for teachers to put their courses, so if I could avoid them using code and having the tiny MCE templates ready for them that would be preferable. Is there a tutorial somewhere that explains how to set this up ? Thx